# How to update files without losing previously written info?

Tags: java, file

I use scanner & PrintWriter for files in **JAVA**. When i create a file & write some info in it & close it, next time i open the file & write something in it the previous info gets overwritten(previous info gets deleted). I need that information. Tell me a way so that i can write the info in file without overwriting(deleting)previous information.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use :

```
new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file , true));
```

Read the documentation of [FileWriter(File file,boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,boolean%29%29)

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> file - a File object to write to
>
> append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

[FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) implements the [Appendable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) interface.The second parameter to the `FileWriter` constructor will tell it to append to the file. It is responsible for being able to add some content to the end of particular file/stream.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your PrintWriter like this to append to the file

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

Last param of the FileWriter is the append flag.